# How to create a ListView in FlutterFlow?

Tags: flutterflow

I'm unable to get ListView to work in FlutterFlow.

I have created an API connection in my app; it's connected to
`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`  and I can see the data is coming through in preview mode. I then linked my list view to this.

I'm unclear on the next steps, nothing I have done works, and every tutorial I have looked at seems to be showing an outdated view of the component that behaves differently.

In my current attempt I have a text box (in fact multiple) within the list view and have used the set text to option to set it to the API field I'm interested in.

But this then gives me another field that says 'Unset' which I have no idea how to resolve.

Can someone outline clearly the steps needed to get a listview displaying any of the fields (pick one) from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` ?